# How to add rain effect to a picture?

Tags: image-processing, language-agnostic

Given a picture, I would like to modify it to create the effect of rain on glass. What steps should I take to achieve this goal?

Suppose we want to add the effect of a single drop of water on a given point in an image, some pixels around that point should be modified in some way: how these pixels should be modified?

Answer (score 2):

Simple way is to just make transparent image that is actually image overlay. That looks like common approach of water drop effects in gimp.

example:

http://natural-drops.deviantart.com/art/drop-of-rain-373710307

I think that in order to make optically correct image one need to have full 3D info of environment, because most optics equations that one needs to simulate correct image includes each object distance.